# Error while deploying a lektor project to hithub on windows dual python install

Tags: python, publish, github-pages, lektor

While trying to deploy to a github page i get the error below:

**Project file**

```
[project]
name = andresperezcera

[servers.production]
target = ghpages://andresperezcera/andresperezcera.github.io?cname=andresperezcera.xyz
```

**Error**

```
λ lektor deploy
Deploying to production
  Build cache: C:\Users\aperez\AppData\Roaming\Lektor\Cache\builds\75d505d25f90dec1e1ee1c5a3f9da1a3
  Target: ghpages://andresperezcera/andresperezcera.github.io?cname=andresperezcera.xyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\aperez\AppData\Local\lektor-cli\lib\Scripts\lektor.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 716, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 696, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1060, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 889, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args[1:], **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 534, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\lektor\cli.py", line 282, in deploy_cmd
    for line in event_iter:
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\lektor\publisher.py", line 583, in publish
    for line in git(['init']):
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\lektor\publisher.py", line 152, in safe_iter
    for line in self:
  File "c:\users\aperez\appdata\local\lektor-cli\lib\lib\site-packages\lektor\publisher.py", line 141, in __iter__
    for l in select.select(streams, [], streams):
select.error: (10038, 'Se intent\xf3 realizar una operaci\xf3n en un elemento que no es un socket')
```

There must be something missing in my project file. Perhaps the connection string doesn't work in windows or perhaps something else.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing was unsupported on Windows until Lektor 2.0.  Upgrading should help.

Comment: How do I upgrade, and congrats on the release

Comment: Just run the installation script again.